# Spring REST custom error-object handling in client

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot, error-handling

## Tl;Dr;

I have a REST controller in Spring-Boot, either returning the MyPojo.class, or RESTError.class.

I then call this controller from another Spring Service with RestTemplate and want to either get a MyPojo Object, or a RESTError Object.

Is there any way to do this, other than checking the raw String and then manually parsing?

## Detailed description

I have two Spring Services.

Lets call them "server-service" and "client-service". The "client-service" has to retrieve a POJO from the "server-service". If something went wrong (Invalid parameter, missing parameter, etc.) a custom error object is returned, that details the error with a 'developer message' and a more broad 'user message'.

That way, if an error occured, I will be able to display the 'user message' in the ui.

This is only meant as a last resort. I should of course do validation in my "client-service" first, before I call the "server-service". Yet, imagine somebody changing the "server-service" without my knowledge...

## "server-service" - Code

**MyPojo**

```
@Getter @Setter @Accessors(chain = true)
public class MyPojo extends MyPojoSuper{
    private String someString;

    //hashCode & equals & toString
}
```

**RESTError**

Following is the custom error object. It has the errorMessage for the general user and the developerMessage for a developer.

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@Getter @Setter @Accessors(chain = true)
public class RESTError extends MyPojoSuper{

    private String errorMessage, developerMessage;

    //hashCode & equals & toString
}
```

**@ControllerAdvice**

The class ExceptionHandlerAdvice will handle all thrown exeptions and return the RESTError.

```
@ControllerAdvice
@RequestMapping("/error")
@Slf4j
public class ExceptionHandlerAdvice {

    @ExceptionHandler(MissingServletRequestParameterException.class)
    @ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
    @ResponseBody
    public RESTError missingServletRequestParameterException(MissingServletRequestParameterException ex) {

    log.info("A parameter['" + ex.getParameterName() +"'] is missing.", ex);
    RESTError error = new RESTError();
    error.setDeveloperMessage(ex.getMessage());
    error.setErrorMessage("The parameter['" + ex.getParameterName() +"'] is missing.");

    return error;
    }
}
```

## "client-service - Code"

**The client method calling the "server-service"**

```
public MyPojo getMyPojo(){
    restTemplate.setErrorHandler(new MyCustomResponseErrorHandler());
    return restTemplate.getForObject(getURLWithParams(), MyPojo.class);
}
```

**The RESTError Client side**

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@Getter @Setter @Accessors(chain = true)
public class RESTError extends MyPojoSuper{

    private String errorMessage, developerMessage;

    //hashCode & equals & toString
}
```

**MyPojoSuper**

```
@Getter @Setter @Accessors(chain = true)
public class MyPojoSuper{
    public boolean error;

    //equals & hashCode & toString
}
```

**The MyCustomResponseErrorHandler**

```
@Slf4j
public class MyCustomResponseErrorHandler implements ResponseErrorHandler {

    @Override
    public boolean hasError(ClientHttpResponse response) throws IOException {
        if (response.getStatusCode() != HttpStatus.OK) {
            log.info("There was an error.");
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void handleError(ClientHttpResponse response) throws IOException {
        if (response.getStatusCode() != HttpStatus.OK) {
            log.info("There was an error.");
        }
    }
}
```

## Problem

**How do I handle my Custom RESTError?**

By using the RestTemplate, I can only parse my JSON once and I can only parse it to one Class (either the MyPojo.class, or RESTError.class).
Therefore, I could parse to a String, check the String and then reparse the JSON into the desired format:

```
public MyPojoSuper getMyPojo() {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    restTemplate.setErrorHandler(new MyCustomResponseErrorHandler());
    String res = restTemplate.getForObject(getURL(), String.class);

    try {
        if (res.contains("\"error\":true")) {
            return mapper.readValue(res, RESTError.class);
        } else {
            return mapper.readValue(res, MyPojo.class);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return new RESTResponse().setError(true);
}
```

I do not like this solution and would appreciate any other suggestions.

Comment: This is saying a `RestErr` _is a_ `SuperMyPojo`.  Is that really true?  It seems `MyPojo` occasionally _has a_ error.  Consider composition instead of inheritance.

Comment: Composition would still not solve my casting problem (I think). If you have a way of composing an object, that solves my problem, please go ahead and post it as an answer.

Comment: Based on [this](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-rest-template-error-handling), consider having `MyCustomResponseErrorHandler` throw an exception when the response has an error.  Since there is an error, the response will have a `RESTErr`which can be deserialized (within the error handler) and wrapped in an exception.

Comment: @Andrew S that works. I am still not 100% satisfied, as I would have wished for an answer like : restTemplate.getForObject(url, ResponseObject.class, ErrorObject.class); But hey, you can't have everything, right ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comment by @Andrew S, here is a solution:

One can register a `ResponseErrorHandler` by creating a class implementing `ResponseErrorHandler` in a custom class and registering it with the `RestTemplate`:

```
@Slf4j
public class MyCustomResponseErrorHandler implements ResponseErrorHandler {

    private ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    @Override
    public boolean hasError(ClientHttpResponse response) throws IOException {
        if (response.getStatusCode() != HttpStatus.OK) {
            log.info("loggin stuff");
            return true;
        }
    return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void handleError(ClientHttpResponse response) throws     JsonParseException, JsonMappingException, IOException{
        if (response.getStatusCode() != HttpStatus.OK) {
            log.info("logging stuff");
            throw new RestErrorExeption(mapper.readValue(response.getBody(),     RESTError.class));
        }
    }
}
```

As shown this class now throws a custom exception, the `RestErrorExeption`. It contains a RESTError object. One can then parse the JSON in the response body by invoking `mapper.readValue(response.getBody(), RESTError.class)`. (Mapper is an instance of com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper)

One can then catch the exception and get the parsed JSON as a POJO from the `RestErrorExeption`:

```
public MyPojoSuper getMyPojo() {
    restTemplate.setErrorHandler(new MyCustomResponseErrorHandler());

    try {
        return restTemplate.getForObject(getURLWithParams(), MyPojo.class);
    } catch (RestErrorExeption e) {
        log.info(e.getMessage());
        return e.getRestError();
    }
}
```

Please note, that the `RESTError.class` and the `MyPojo.class` need the `MyPojoSuper.class` as their parent to be properly handled.

Answer (score 0):

Your RESTError class is a subclass of MyPojoSuper class

```
RESTError extends MyPojoSuper
```

And in your try-catch, you are specifically catching IOException

```
try {
        if (res.contains("\"error\":true")) {
            return mapper.readValue(res, RESTError.class);
        } else {
            return mapper.readValue(res, MyPojo.class);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Can you share your class code for MyPojoSuper.java please? Should it be at least subclass of IOException so that it can be caught in your try catch.

If I understood your problem correctly.

Comment: The IOException is thrown by com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(String json, Class returnObject). I added the MyPojoSuper class

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, when you use `restTemplate`, it throws `HttpStatusCodeException` if the response code does not equal `2xx`. that's why I think you have to catch the exception. Like

```
    try {
      restTemplate.getForObject(url, MyPojo.class);
     } catch (HttpStatusCodeException e) {
         if (e.getStatusCode() == 404) {

           String body = e.getResponseBodyAsString();

           // do smth with error json
        }
    }
```